# Drupal 8 - Translate string from template

Tags: translation, drupal-8, drupal-templates

I have texts in different screens of my template that correspond to headers, links, etc. and that I need them to appear translated in my web page.

How can I enter words, text strings, etc. and put the translation in all the languages of my site from the admin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in twig template you can translate value by this way :

```
{{ "Most Recent"|t }}
```

another example :

```
<a class="button" href="#">{{ "Show most recent item"|t }}</a>
```

more documentation here :
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/translation-api/overview